# how can i project a camera onto a cube as a Texture in jMonkeyEngine 3?

Tags: java, camera, jmonkeyengine

how can i project a camera onto a cube as a Texture  in JMonkeyEngine3?
would you mind helping me?

I try to do it by this piece of code but it dosent work:

```
private void addCamera() {
    Camera c = new Camera(100, 100);
    c.setViewPort(0, 1, 0, 1);
    c.setLocation(Vector3f.ZERO);

    ViewPort v = new ViewPort("c", c);
    v.attachScene(rootNode);
    FrameBuffer fb = v.getOutputFrameBuffer();
    fb.setDepthBuffer(Format.Depth);
    Texture2D niftytex = new Texture2D(1024, 768, Format.RGB8);
    fb.setColorTexture(niftytex);

    Box b = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, 1, 1, 1);
    Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);
    Material mat = new Material(assetManager,     "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
    mat.setTexture("m_ColorMap", niftytex);
    /**
     * Here comes the texture!
     */
    geom.setMaterial(mat);
    localRootNode.attachChild(geom);

}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? I could spot a number of issues here: 1) `fb` is NULL. 2) You need to set `v.setOutputFrameBuffer()` 3) The material parameter is `ColorMap` without the `m_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `TestRenderToTexture` example in the `jme3-examples` project, you will achieve what you want. You can put the whole thing in a util class and just call it from your project (I've done that myself).